# How to update to 11.04 through flash drive?

Tags: 10.10, 11.04, flash, updates, drive

My internet is pretty slow on one of my Ubuntu computers and it is running 10.10. I just want to know if I am able to update to 11.04 through my flash drive. I would like to know. Thank You.

Answer (score 5):

[Download the alternate version](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/alternative-download#alternate) and mount it like this:

```
sudo mount -o loop -t iso9660 /PATH-TO-FILE/ubuntu-11.04-alternate-i386.iso /media/cdrom
```

Then open a terminal and enter this command (or use Alt+F2 and enter this):

```
gksu "sh /media/cdrom/cdromupgrade"
```

After that the upgrade process will be started.

Answer (score 0):

If you've spare disk space, you do not even need a flash drive.
Follow the [upgrade instructions from the Ubuntu Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NattyUpgrades#Upgrading%20Using%20the%20Alternate%20CD/DVD).

1. Downloading the [alternative ISO](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NattyUpgrades#Upgrading%20Using%20the%20Alternate%20CD/DVD) to your home directory. **Download the Kubuntu iso if you're using Kubuntu (KDE)**
2. Mount the using:

   ```
   sudo mount -o loop ubuntu-11.04-alternate-amd64.iso /media/cdrom
   ```

   if you're using KDE:

   ```
   sudo mount -o loop kubuntu-11.04-alternate-amd64.iso /media/cdrom
   ```
3. Start the installer by executing:

   ```
   gksu /media/cdrom/cdromupgrade
   ```

   if you're using Kubuntu:

   ```
   kdesudo /media/cdrom/cdromupgrade
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need at least a computer which has a decent internet connection to download Ubuntu 11.04 ISO, once you're done downloading the LiveCD image, you can create a bootable flash drive from the image using popular tools like [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net) or [Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) and once you create a bootable flash drive, you can use it to upgrade all your computers running Ubuntu 10.10. You'll be able to make clean install of 11.04 or will be able to upgrade, thus keeping all your files safe. Obviously, you're computers should be able to boot from flashdrive, which largely depends on BIOS settings of your computers.